# Why does cheryl change her name often?

Tags: analysis, archer

In Archer season 1 why does Cheryl (shown below) change her name quite frequently?

She goes by Carol, Carina, Crystal etc. in the first few episodes.

[image: x]

Comment: I think that it's as simple as it being a running joke. I seem to remember a line that goes something like "What are you called today, Cheryl?". This combined with her, obvious, issues just helps to explain that she's someone that you should be wary of

Comment: It's curious that after those first few episodes, she's always called "Cheryl", but in the Netflix subtitles she's permanently identified as "Cheryl/Carol."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

She first changes her name to Carol because that's what Archer called her while they were in a relationship.

From IMDB:
["Archer: Training Day (#1.2)" (2010)](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0199489/quotes)

> **Cyril Figgis:** Hello Cheryl.
>
> **Cheryl:** It's Carol.
>
> **Sterling Archer:** Uh, since when?
>
> **Cheryl:** Since I had it legally changed because you always call me
>   Carol.

She claimed that Carina "better captured [her] sensual womanhood" in the episode "Killing Utne".

Finally, the change to Cristal was done to curry favor with Conway Stern in "Diversity Hire". Cristal being the name of a wine that was briefly popular amongst rappers, which in Cheryl's mind probably equated to all black people including Conway.

But yes, it has become a running joke exemplify the character's personality issues.